# XARGS with for loop pr

Tags: bash, for-loop, xargs

Hi I am working in bash shell with a file of file names that contains multiple files for the same sample on different lines

```
file.txt
Filename1_1 SampleName1
Filename1_2 SampleName1
Filename2_1 SampleName2
Filename2_2 SampleName2
```

I am trying to use xargs with a for loop to pass the filenames into one argument (i.e print Filename1_1 FileName1_2).
Which would be the effect of :

```
cat file.txt | xargs bash -c 'echo ${0} ${2}'
```

Since it is quite a long file i cannot use this repeatedly and thought using a for loop will help. But isn't producing the output i expected
Here is what i thought would be simple to do.

```
for (( i = 0,j=2; i<=63; i= i+4,j=j+4 ))
  do
  cat file.txt | xargs bash -c 'echo ${i} ${j}'
done
```

However running this loops through and prints a bunch of blank lines.

Anyone have an idea of getting this to work like i want?

I am looking for an output that looks like below to pass each line to another function

```
Filename1_1 Filename1_2
Filename2_1 Filename2_2
Filename3_1 Filename3_2
Filename4_1 Filename4_2
```

Comment: Can you explain what output do you want? without the broken `xargs` approach

Comment: I want an output that looks like <br/> Filename1_1 Filename1_2 <br/> Filename2_1 Filename2_2 etc.

Comment: `cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt | paste -d' ' - -`

Comment: `'echo ${i} ${j}'` is passed literally, you would have to use double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `-n2` and  specify maximum number of arguments.

```
<file.txt xargs -n2 bash -c 'echo $1 $2' _
```